# Do plug nozzles improve efficiency on lower throttle settings?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design

[Plug nozzles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_nozzle) are used to adjust for the overexpansion/underexpansion of the exhaust with altitude. Do they also adjust for overexpansion/underexpansion of the exhaust caused by lowered mass flow experienced at lower throttle settings? Or does throttling not have an effect on the exhaust shape?